# Init(coder:) has not Implement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viper-architecture

I'm doing creating an App with VIP Clean and I'm having trouble calling the HomeViewController on LoginRouter.

I tried it in a few ways, instantiating the homeviewcontroller and passing the HomeViewController init information like this: `let homeViewController = HomeViewController(interactor: HomeInteractor(repository: HomeRepository(), user: user), router: HomeRouter(navigationController: navigationController), presenter: HomePresenter())`

And I get the same message, and I don't know how to fix it ...

LoginRouter:

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol LoginRouting{
    func routeToHome(login:LoginViewController, user: UserRealm)
}

protocol LoginDataPassing{
    var dataStore: LoginDataStore? { get }
}
class LoginRouter: NSObject, LoginRouting {
//MARK: - Navigation init

    weak var viewController: LoginViewController?
    var dataStore: LoginDataStore?

    var navigationController = UIViewController()

    init(navigationController: UIViewController){
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

     //MARK: - Routing and Navigations

    func routeToHome(login: LoginViewController, user: UserRealm) {
        login.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
        let home = 
                UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: 
                "HomeViewController")
    
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(home, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
     }
  }
```

HomeViewController:

```
import UIKit


protocol HomeDisplayLogic: class{
    func displaySomething(viewModel: Home.ViewModel)
}


class HomeViewController: UIViewController, HomeDisplayLogic {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLb: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userAccontLb: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userBalance: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!




var router: HomeRouter?
private var interector: HomeInteractor
private var presenter: HomePresenter
private var tableViewDataSource: HomeDataSource?

init(interactor: HomeInteractor, router: HomeRouter, presenter: HomePresenter) {
    self.interector = interactor
    self.interector.presenter = presenter
    self.presenter = presenter
    self.router = router
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

 
 // MARK: - View lifecycle



   override func viewDidLoad() {
       
       populateInformations()
       setupView()
           
      }
   
   private func setupView() {
        presenter.viewController = self
          
        HomeDataSource.setupHome(tableView: tableview)
        tableViewDataSource = HomeDataSource(presenter: presenter)
        tableview.dataSource = tableViewDataSource
        tableview.delegate = tableViewDataSource
      }
 
 // MARK: - PopulateInformations
 
 func populateInformations(){
    let request = Home.Request(userId: interector.user.userId ?? "1.0")
    interector.getInfoStatements(request: request)
 }

   func displaySomething(viewModel: Home.ViewModel) {
    
  }

 }
```

When I call Home I get this message: `Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file`

could someone explain to me what can be wrong or how to correctly pass the information from one viewController to another?

Answer (score 1):

Because you initiate your viewController from storyboard, so the

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

will be triggered. It ins't implemented yet, so it will be crashed.

to fix it, you could remove both init method from your viewController
then instead of set interactor, router from init method, you could make it as optional and set it as normal properties.

Comment: So, i try your solution, but i can`t show information in running app

Answer (score 1):

You're doing some really strange things with your initializers...

The compiler is complaining because `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is not the same as `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, the fact that it's not optional is a huge difference.

You also have your own initializer with more parameters, but that initializer calls to a `super` `init` that doesn't use the `coder` value. You should call `super.init(coder: coder)` or even `self.init(coder: coder)` instead. But as it stands, `UIStoryboard. instantiateViewController` doesn't know about your custom initializer, so it won't even be called.

You have two options:

If you are targeting below iOS 13, you'll need to use `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and remove your custom initializer. You'll also need to make your other variables optional and set their values once the view controller is created.

If you are targeting iOS 13+ ONLY (which means you WON'T support iOS 12 and under), [you can use this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/3213989-instantiateviewcontroller), which will give you the `NSCoder` value that you can pass to the custom initializer. You'll still need to get rid of the `?` in both of the initializers you have though.

It'll look something like this:

```
let home = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: 
                "HomeViewController") { coder in
  HomeViewController(coder: coder, interactor: interactor, router: router, presenter: presenter)
}
```

(I don't see the rest of the required properties in your code so I just put their names, but I'm assuming you have a way to get to them)

Comment: I was testing this and forgot to change it to ask the question ... I will change it. But I will test this solution, but would there be another way to do this if it is possible with IOS 12 for example?

Comment: I testting but i have same message ```Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file```

Comment: No, there's no way to use a custom `coder` initializer on iOS 12 and lower. And the reason for your crash is because your implementation of `init(coder:)` only throws a fatal error. Put actual code in there and then call `super`.

Comment: I understood, but how could I solve this? in init should I put ```super.init ()``` or something?

Comment: This is pretty basic initializer stuff, look it up or just try it yourself, you'll learn more that way than if I give you all the required code.